# Preprocessors in [C]

Tags: c, macros

I am working on Preprocessors and according to me otput should be 50 50 in this case! My cocept of preprocessor are affected due to this question please explain the concept vividly and output! Thanks in advance

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #define a 10
   void foo(){printf("\n%d",a);}
   int main()
   {
    #define a 50
    printf("\n%d",a);
    foo();
    getchar();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is just terrible code.  Due in tomorrow morning?

Comment: When you compiled it and checked out the post-preprocessor dump, what did you find?

Answer (score 3):

Let's just go through it step by step:

```
#define a 10
void foo(){printf("\n%d",a);}
int main()
{
    #define a 50
    printf("\n%d",a);
    foo();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

first replacement makes this:

```
void foo(){printf("\n%d",10);}
int main()
{
    #define 10 50
    printf("\n%d",10);
    foo();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

secondly, we will be redefining the number 10, which is dangerous

```
void foo(){printf("\n%d",10);}
int main()
{
    printf("\n%d",50);
    foo();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I would just try to avoid this kind of code, by making sure your compiler reports this as a warning (or even promote it to an error), like `warning: 'a' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]`

Answer (score 1):

First or all, you really should not look at the preprocessor as part of the language, but as a separate program that runs before the compiler and transforms the source into a [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) that the compiler uses. Thinking like that makes it easier to understand that the language used by the preprocessor is not the same as C, which means the rules of the C language doesn't apply to the preprocessor.

Preprocessor macros are not like C variables and can't be used as such, and macros can't be redefined since there is no scoping like in the C language. A macro once defined last for the rest of the input file and all following included files.

Comment: But still we are redifining it simply gives warning nothing else! Than major concern is how to explain output. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Imagine each pre processor line constituting a script runner at compilation time. The most peculiar thing about this script though is that it affects the following code. Thus, if you want to change the value of a given macro in the middle of your program, you need to undef if before making another define. Doing so will stop the macro replacement as soon as the undef is met and your code will work as intended.